# Decrypt password in phpmyadmin with strange type

Tags: joomla, passwords, phpmyadmin, encryption

Good day! I have a quite strange problem. I have installed joomla on one of my websites about 7 months ago and completely forgot my password. Easy to find out right? So i logged into php myadmin in order to decrypt it with md5decrypter and my password is something like or to be more precise exactly this **ffeb0b0d7b626671abc1c63a65239368:8tRMglEvI81jDHydqR5eufCRQy4TPJtS**

I`ve never encountered something like that and don`t know which format is it. Can anyone help ?

Comment: Not a programming question.  But you cannot decrypt something that's been hashed; the best you can do is find a collision.

Comment: That's what things like md5decrypter do.

Comment: Why would you need to decrypt your password? If you've forgotten is simply reset it? Plus it may take quite a while to "crack" your password if it contains more than 4 characters and special symbols `!@#$%^&*()_+...`

Comment: I`ve tried with md5 and it didn`t recognized the hash and i'd like to find it out because i honestly i would like to gain access back to my site. Cannot reset it! I`ve encrypted a new password in md5 and doesn`t work

Comment: Joomla default uses a salted md5 not md5.  Did you Google at all because there is a whole page in the Joomla docs wiki about this not to mention a million articles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best way is:
1. make a new user
2. set password for new user
3. go to phpmyadmin and copy new user hashed password and paste in admin
4. login with admin and new user password!

if you cannot create new user you can install new joomla(in localhost or server)

Answer (score 1):

For future reference if you have forgotten your Joomla! admin password there is a tool available from the [Joomla! Extension Directory](http://extensions.joomla.org/) that makes the process simple.

[Reset Admin Password](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/tools/security-tools/13785)